# Should there be a minimum rep needed to comment on a question?

Tags: discussion

It seems that users with low rep are not allowed to comment on questions. This sometimes leads to them posting answers which are more in the nature of comments, or possibly worse, answering a question the OP did not ask, or only posting an incomplete answer. An example is here:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210015/how-to-use-voltage-genrated-by-dc-motor-what-type-of-circuit-i-require-for-it

Should we allow users to post comments at the same rep as they are able to post answers, or even allow posting of comments at a lower rep than that which allows them to post answers?

Comment: just imagine the alternative. I think SE was there, did it, considered it worse.

Comment: This is a network wide privilege level issue.

Comment: Down votes can push poor answers farther down the scroll screen (and out of view).

Comments can corrupt threads for upvoted (good) answers. Or bots could pollute the thread and distract from good comments appropriate to the thread.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely keep a minimal rep requirement for comments.  It's an anti-robot measure.  If you're a user of a certain rep on another stack, you get bonus points that immediately allow commenting on a new stack.  A review process would just cause more use for users and mods.

Answer (score 3):

It's a valid question. As it is, the newbie posts an answer, and *sometimes* this gets flagged by a community reviewer looking at posts by new users, which brings it to the attention of the moderators. Then a moderator needs to review it again and then either delete it or turn it into a comment.

This is a very indirect and unreliable process. It would probably make more sense to allow comments, but also put them into a review queue just like we do with posts. This would make the process both more reliable and more direct.